# T-SQL Regex on postcodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard

I'm trying to use T-SQL regex on postcodes. I'm trying to get a condition where

- The first letter can be a W or a B.

  - If the first letter is a W then the second must be S
  - If the first letter is a B then the second must me a number

What I've got so far is this...

```
[WB][S1-9]
```

but it doesn't do conditions, this would also bring out postcodes with W1 for example, which I don't want.

Comment: `postcode like 'WS%' or postcode like 'B[0-9]%'`?

Comment: Note that SQL Server does not support Regex; just basic pattern matching.

Comment: Don't have access to Sql Server currently, but I think you can use `postcode like '[W][S]%' OR postcode like '[B][0-9]%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this solve your needs

```
-- DDL+DML: sample table with some rows
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T
GO
CREATE TABLE T(txt varchar(10))
GO
INSERT T(txt) VALUES
    ('WSfgsd'),
    ('Werwgerh'),
    ('B12uyktgfd'),
    ('Bcyec'),
    ('tybi')
GO

------ Solution option 1
SELECT txt
FROM T
WHERE 
    txt like 'WS%' -- If the first letter is a W then the second must be S = meaning start with WS
    OR
    (txt like 'B%' and SUBSTRING(txt,2,1) like '[0-9]') -- If the first letter is a B then the second must me a number
GO
```